# Get value from JSON string

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON string:

```
{"d":"{\"Foo\":7,\"Bar\":5,\"Foobar\":3}"}
```

And the corresponding invocation in my js file:

```
$.getJSON("Foo.svc/GetSomeFoo", function (response) {
            alert(response["Foo"]);
            alert(response["Bar"]);
            alert(response["Foobar"]);
        });
```

Just trying to write out the values, but can't seem to get it out.
It is probably very simple, but I am not finding anything helpful while googling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON has embedded JSON. You need to do:

```
var d = JSON.parse(response.d);
alert(d.Foo);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an object named `d` as the outer object, you will need to get your data via it.

For ex: `response.d["Foo"]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
alert(response.d["Foo"]);
```

`response` gives you this: `{"d":"{\"Foo\":7,\"Bar\":5,\"Foobar\":3}"}`
`response.d` will give you: `{\"Foo\":7,\"Bar\":5,\"Foobar\":3}`
and finally `response.d["Foo"]` or `response.d.Foo` will give you: `7`

Comment: Ahhh so simple it was. the 'd' is something new since last I messed with json a couple of years ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this -

```
 alert(response.d.Foo);
```