# Get specific data from json using php

Tags: php, json

This is json data i received:

```
{"id":"8","cardnum":"5678887","point_collected":"26","date":"2015-05-06"}

{"id":"15","cardnum":"3435435","point_collected":"20","date":"2015-05-04"}

{"id":"11","cardnum":"5678887","point_collected":"50","date":"2015-05-03"}

{"id":"12","cardnum":"5678887","point_collected":"80","date":"2015-05-02"}

{"id":"14","cardnum":"5678887","point_collected":"10","date":"2015-05-02"}
```

**I want to get the "cardnum" for comparison with my $usercard, and display all the result with the same "cardnum" and encode into json again.**

This is my current code:

```
 $decodeTrans=json_decode($transJson, true);

        $response = array();

        $usercard = "5678887";

       foreach ($decodeTrans as $dt)
                {      
                    $membercard = $dt['cardnum'];

                    if ($membercard == $usercard)
                    {

                       $response["success"] = 1;
                       $response ['id'] = $dt['id'];
                       $response ['card_number'] = $membercard;
                       $response ['point_collected'] = $dt['point']; 
                       $response ['date'] = $dt['date'];

                       echo json_encode($response);

                    }
                }  

    }
```

}

**I get this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.**

Comment: if you're getting that literal JSON string then its an invalid one, thats why after decode and feeding it into the `foreach`, it spewed the error

Comment: What you have posted is not a URL, nor is it valid JSON.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634016/get-value-from-json-string

Answer (score 0):

Your input is not a valid JSON string. However, each line is still a valid JSON string. Update your code to split the `$transJson` and convert each line to PHP object using `json_decode`:

```
$response = array();
$usercard = "5678887";
foreach(explode("\n", $transJson) as $line)
{
    $dt = json_decode(trim($line), true);
    $membercard = $dt['cardnum'];

    if ($membercard == $usercard)
    {

       $response["success"] = 1;
       $response ['id'] = $dt['id'];
       $response ['card_number'] = $membercard;
       $response ['point_collected'] = $dt['point_collected']; 
       $response ['date'] = $dt['date'];

       echo json_encode($response);

    }
}
```

The demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3335a3fa9edb5a3b8d7e73fd85d4bad806e5ac92

Comment: this is not working. I get a blank page after using this code. what is the problem?

Comment: There is an error in your original code, the `$dt['point']` is not set, I have update the code and use `$dt['point_collected']` instead. You can view the result in the link at the end of my answer now.