# is there a way to GET account_name value from the below code and parse into json

Tags: php, api, curl

here is my code below ,i need to get the value of account_name from the beow API request, kindly go through it and advise. The only value i need to get is **account_name** value. Kindly help out thanks

`````
 $curl = curl_init();
 switch ($method){
    case "POST":
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       if ($data)
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
       break;
    case "PUT":
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
       if ($data)
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                              
       break;
    default:
       if ($data)
          $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
 }
 // OPTIONS:
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "authorization: Bearer sk_test_df78c3c2d08ea1f266b8b19524a249e77c0eaa14",
  "content-type: application/json",
 ));
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
 // EXECUTE:
 $result = curl_exec($curl);
 if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
 curl_close($curl);
 return $result;
}

$bank="033";
$accno=2056194452;

$get_data = callAPI('GET', 'https://api.paystack.co/bank/resolve?account_number='.$accno.'&bank_code='.urlencode($bank), false);
$response = json_decode(json_encode($get_data), true);
echo $response;````

#Result of code will output the below:#

`{ "status": true, "message": "Account number resolved", "data": { "account_number": "2056194452", "account_name": "OLADEPO WISDOM IBRAHIM", "bank_id": 18 } }`
`````

Comment: why do you encode and decode? what have you tried? Also, take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634016/get-value-from-json-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API returns JSON data, so there is not reason encode it. 
If you use json_decode and set the "assoc" parameter to true (like you already have), it should return an associative array. You can then get the  "account_name" variable from the array.

```
$get_data = callAPI('GET', 'https://api.paystack.co/bank/resolve?account_number='.$accno.'&bank_code='.urlencode($bank), false);
$response = json_decode($get_data, true);
echo $response['data']['account_name'];
```